# Google FCM for Android installed via email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

Am setting up push notifications for my Android App. The App is not published into Google Play Store yet. Am testing this app by installing APK directly on my mobile.

Can FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging Server) send notifications to mobile phones which has done installation from APK files directly (not through playstore)?

Just want to know how FCM will work in this case?

Comment: yes if the phone have Google play services installed

Answer (score 0):

**YES. FCM can send notifications to your app as long as your device is registered to receive messages with FCM server**

On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance. FCM Server will manage the registration token and use this token to identify your device and send notifications. Note that the registration token can be changed in some case [View more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register)

You can test by sending notifications to your device from [Notification Composer](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification/compose?pli=1). Select target is `Single Device` and `your registration token` is target device.

```
// Get the current registration token 
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

To handle message follow [the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do by using Firebase console

1. In firebase console select Function tab which is present in left part of firebase console.
2. Download node.js in your system and code it according to your wish in node.js.

Firebase token should be mention in your java code.